# Having a hard time trying to get jQuery to work with WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I looked at other examples in this forum but nothing worked. The script works just fine in a standalone Bootstrap 4 file, however in WordPress it does not work at all. 
Using "Understrap" child theme. It's a button that shows in mobile view to close/open a pan.
[Here is the Codepen](https://codepen.io/zawx/pen/bGNXROm)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#SearchArea').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
            $('#closeButton').html('Open');
        });
        $('#SearchArea').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
            $('#closeButton').html('Close');
        });

    });
```

Comment: You mean the mobile menu's "sandwich"?

Comment: Where exactly are you putting this code snippet in wordpress?

Comment: I added it to footer.php. I move it to the top, bottom, and everywhere I could think of but it does not work at all. It loads after <?php wp_footer(); ?>

Comment: Not the mobile toggle. There is a yellow button that show only on mobile(sm). The toggle works, just cannot get the text on the button to change as in the codepen.

Comment: any error showing in console?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress loads jQuery in "no conflict" mode in order to avoid name space collisions with other libraries.

Wrap your script in an anonymous function that maps jQuery to `$` like this:

```
(function($) {
  $('#SearchArea').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('#closeButton').html('Open');
  });
  $('#SearchArea').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('#closeButton').html('Close');
  });
})( jQuery );
```

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress $ is not used for jquery. Try Below Code I think this work for you.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        jQuery('#SearchArea').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
            jQuery('#closeButton').html('Open');
        });
        jQuery('#SearchArea').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
            jQuery('#closeButton').html('Close');
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help. Mistake was on my end. Spelling mistake on the ID. Can't believe I spent all this time trying to fix the problem...lol